# viewDidAppear: called before view appears with nested UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, uistoryboardsegue

## The context

I have a view controller hierarchy:

1. A container `UIViewController`: **A** with an embedded child `UIPageViewController`. **A** overlays various stuff on top of **B** and tinkers with the navigation, and other stuff.
2. The embedded `UIPageViewController`: **B**.
3. The pages: **C** that are displayed by **B**.

When **A** is instantiated, **B** is embedded in it. My override of `prepareForSegue:sender` in **A** causes **C** to be instantiated and set as **B**'s current page:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"EmbedPagesSegue"])
  {
    UIPageViewController *const pagesViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [pagesViewController setDataSource: self];
    [pagesViewController setDelegate: self];
    [self setPagesViewController: pagesViewController];

    UIViewController *const initialPage = [self initialDisplayedPage];
    [pagesViewController 
      setViewControllers: @[initialPage] 
      direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward 
      animated: NO 
      completion:nil];

    // Point X.
    // Segue not yet started.
    // A is not on screen yet!
    // C has already been added to B
  }
}
```

## The Problem

**C** overrides `viewDidAppearAnimated:`.

When the initial page is presented, **C**'s `viewDidAppearAnimated:` is called at **Point X**, before **C**'s view can be on screen because **B** has yet to be added to **A** (the segue is just setting up).

This is a problem because **C**'s implementations of `viewDidAppearAnimated:` needs to be able to reference the  **A** that it has appeared in.

For subsequent pages, the embedding segue has completed, so **B** *is* added to **A**, and *is* on screen. In these cases the `viewDidAppearAnimated:` call to **C** is appropriate.

## Or, to put it another way.

`viewDidAppearAnimated:` should actually be called `viewDidAppearAnimatedInParentButTheParentMightNotHaveAppearedYet:`

## The question(s)

1. Is there a clean way for **C** to access **A** during this initial set up process? I could do some kind of hack like defer the setup with `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, but I'd rather not.
2. Am I implementing the embedding segue in the wrong way?
3. Is this just a bad design – in which case, what instead?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you accessing A from C? `parentViewController.parentViewController`?

Comment: @LeoNatan Pretty much. Doesn't smell too good, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is a bad design to make assumptions about the view or controller hierarchy above the point you are at. So making assumptions about parent view controllers or superviews is normally not recommended. In your case, if you need to access A from C, create public API in C where you can pass A in some form (most likely, `weak`ly), so it can configure itself.

Comment: Perhaps a protocol defined by **A** that **C** can implement, and **A** can send protocol messages to the **C**s it presents at appropriate times.

Comment: I am thinking the other way around (aka delegation pattern), where A calls public API methods of C, while C calls public protocol methods of `id<Aprotocol>`.

Comment: How would you have C get hold of the A reference? I've set up a protocol implemented by A that's called on appropriate events. A passes itself to the protocol implementation when it makes the calls, so C doesn't need to get hold of A. This seems to work okay, although I've still got some cheating going on where C looks up A by nefarious means – I'm not sure if these will clean out easily of not with this approach.

Comment: You should pass A to C when you instantiate it. From your description, A is the controller of B, and creates C and puts it in B. So A can put itself in C before it is put in B, thus allowing it to perform what it needs.